# Date Differences from different outputs

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to find out how long it takes till a customer orders again in my eshop.

Name of the list eshop_flat_sales_order

```
customer_email created_at status
------------------------------------
a(at)a.com     12.1.10    complete
b(at)a.com     14.2.10    cancelled
c(at)a.com     16.1.10    complete
a(at)a.com     18.1.10    complete
c(at)a.com     18.1.10    complete
b(at)a.com     20.1.10    complete
```

With the query

```
SELECT *
FROM eshop_flat_sales_order
ORDER BY customer_email
```

Ill get all the emails with the date in orders. Like this:

```
customer_email created_at status
------------------------------------
a(at)a.com     12.1.10    complete
a(at)a.com     18.1.10    complete
b(at)a.com     14.2.10    cancelled
b(at)a.com     20.1.10    complete
c(at)a.com     16.1.10    complete
c(at)a.com     18.1.10    complete
```

Now it would be great to get a query which tells me how long it took a(at)a.com to order again. In the example it would be 6 days. For c(at)a.com it would be 2 days. Then in the end I need the average of all this dates but I should manage that :)

Thanks so much for the answers

Comment: What format are the dates stored as?  I'm kind of hoping `DATE`?  Also is there a central table which stores `customer_email`s?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query to return the latest gap, in days, for each customer, using JOIN:

```
SELECT e1.customer_email, DATEDIFF(e1.created_at, e2.created_at) AS gap
FROM eshop_flat_sales_order e1
LEFT JOIN eshop_flat_sales_order e2
  ON e2.customer_email = e1.customer_email
  AND e2.created_at < e1.created_at
LEFT JOIN eshop_flat_sales_order e3
  ON e3.customer_email = e1.customer_email
  AND e3.created_at < e2.created_at
WHERE e3.customer_email IS NULL
ORDER BY e1.customer_email
```

This query assumes that `created_at` is a `DATE` field.

It will return `NULL` for `gap` where a customer only has one order. If you don't want to return results for customers with only one order, change the first join from `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`.

Here's another version that only considers `complete` orders:

```
SELECT e1.customer_email, DATEDIFF(e1.created_at, e2.created_at) AS gap
FROM eshop_flat_sales_order e1
LEFT JOIN eshop_flat_sales_order e2
  ON e2.customer_email = e1.customer_email
  AND e2.created_at < e1.created_at
  AND e2.status = 'complete'
LEFT JOIN eshop_flat_sales_order e3
  ON e3.customer_email = e1.customer_email
  AND e3.created_at < e2.created_at
  AND e3.status = 'complete'
WHERE e1.status = 'complete'
  AND e3.customer_email IS NULL
ORDER BY e1.customer_email
```

This would show all the gaps between all the corresponding orders, for all the customers:

```
SELECT e1.customer_email, DATEDIFF(e1.created_at, e2.created_at) AS gap
FROM eshop_flat_sales_order e1
JOIN eshop_flat_sales_order e2
  ON e2.customer_email = e1.customer_email
  AND e2.created_at < e1.created_at
  AND e2.status = 'complete'
LEFT JOIN eshop_flat_sales_order e3
  ON e3.customer_email = e1.customer_email
  AND e3.created_at < e1.created_at
  AND e3.created_at > e2.created_at
  AND e3.status = 'complete'
WHERE e1.status = 'complete'
  AND e3.customer_email IS NULL
ORDER BY e1.customer_email ASC, e1.created_at DESC
```

This would show the average gaps for each customer:

```
SELECT e1.customer_email, AVG(DATEDIFF(e1.created_at, e2.created_at)) AS gap
FROM eshop_flat_sales_order e1
JOIN eshop_flat_sales_order e2
  ON e2.customer_email = e1.customer_email
  AND e2.created_at < e1.created_at
  AND e2.status = 'complete'
LEFT JOIN eshop_flat_sales_order e3
  ON e3.customer_email = e1.customer_email
  AND e3.created_at < e1.created_at
  AND e3.created_at > e2.created_at
  AND e3.status = 'complete'
WHERE e1.status = 'complete'
  AND e3.customer_email IS NULL
GROUP BY e1.customer_email
```

Comment: Thank you! So it means if there is a customer assuming its a(at)a.com with 3 orders it takes the second and third?

Comment: Yes, always the gap between the latest two orders.

Comment: ok thanks; and would there be a way to see the gaps of all the orders, probably adding another line?

Comment: I thought you were going to manage that. :) I updated my answer to include the other queries. I hope you'll study the query to see how it's done and forever grok the join.

Comment: Thanks...i am just lost in this now...i tried forever...no my server thought he rather does not work anymore...argh

Comment: I learned to join like this from the book [SQL AntiPatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns). I recommend it. It's a fun read.

Answer (score 0):

To get the result as requested, try the following:

```
SELECT
    customer_email,
    DATEDIFF(MAX(date), MIN(date))
FROM eshop_flat_sales_order
GROUP BY customer_email
```

Comment: That would find the gap between first and last order, rather than the gaps between orders chronologically.  Also there would be no difference between a user that hasn't reordered, and one that reordered on the same day (as in both cases DATEDIFF(MAX,MIN) would be 0)

Comment: to get the gap between orders chronologically you may have to add an  `ORDER BY created_at` to the end of the query

Comment: Not really as it'd still group on unique customer_email's.  The only way I could conceive would involve a join on, for example, `t1.date < t2.date` however would need some pruning to ensure it only linked to the next available date.  Either way this is a bit nasty + my lunch break was over - but might be something you can work with.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
this query will give you the customer, the last order and the previous order.
Check if it reflects what you need. If yes, just do a datediff on the columns:

```
with last_order as
(
    select customer_email, max(created_at) as max_order, max (ID) as max_id
    from eshop_flat_sales_order 
    where status='complete'
    group by customer_email
)
Select customer_email, MAX_ORDER, 
(select top 1 created_at 
 from eshop_flat_sales_order o 
 where customer_email=lo.customer_email and ID!= lo.max_id and status='complete'
 order by created_at desc) as PREVIOUS_ORDER
from last_order LO
```

Do you always have 2 records per customer? If yes, try this:

```
select customer_email, datediff(day, min(created_at),max(created_at))
from eshop_flat_sales_order
where status='complete'
group by customer_email
having count(*)=2
```

Comment: Thank you all soo much. There are customers which do have 7 orders, there are customers with 2 orders, there are customers with only one order.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be best to do it with SQL Variables... so you can always use whatever the last person was and their corresponding date of activity...

```
SELECT 
      PreSort.customer_email, 
      @lastDate as LastOrderDate,
      PreSort.Created_At,
      if( @lastCust = PreSort.customer_email, 
         datediff( @lastDate, PreSort.Created_At ), null ) as DaysDiff,
      @lastDate := PreSort.Created_At as PreserveDate,
      @lastCust := PreSort.customer_email as PreserveCustomer
   FROM 
      ( select efso.customer_email,
               efso.created_at 
            from eshop_flat_sales_order AS efso
            where efso.status = 'complete'
            order by efso.customer_email,
                     efso.created_at ) PreSort,
      (SELECT @lastCust := '', @lastDate := null ) AS SqlVars
```

Now, you are looking for last time BETWEEN ACTUAL Orders... so you have the status of "complete" or "cancelled" vs just visiting your site and ATTEMPTING an order..

should create a result cursor something like

```
customer_email LastOrderDate created_at DaysDiff   PreserveDate PreserveCustomer
-------------- ------------- ---------- ---------- ------------ ----------------
a(at)a.com     NULL          12.1.10    NULL       12.1.10      a(at)a.com
a(at)a.com     12.1.10       18.1.10    6          18.1.10      a(at)a.com
b(at)a.com     NULL          20.1.10    NULL       20.1.10      b(at)a.com
c(at)a.com     NULL          16.1.10    NULL       16.1.10      c(at)a.com
c(at)a.com     16.1.10       18.1.10    2          18.1.10      c(at)a.com
```

Now, if you want averages, you can roll THESE records up and get average from DaysDiff.  However, you would probably want to apply WHERE to remove the "NULL" entries that indicate the FIRST order for a person and just leave those that specifically HAD a second order.  You could even apply GROUPING values for first date, last date, total orders too.